Unlock Nokia TA-1198 FRP
I've been trying to find a safe way to unlock my device's frp lock on a computer. Can you advise a tourist "I don't know how to use complex commands". And I don't want to learn how to open without a computer. On my computer, adb and command line tools are working fine. However, is the new firmware an option. How? I don't have a company to support me.
